# Using a dictionary as switch without assigning it to a variable

Tags: python, dictionary, switch-statement, key

The following two "switches" work:

```
return {
    1: func1,
    2: func2,
    3: func3
}[random.choice([1,2,3])]()

d = {
    1: func1,
    2: func2,
    3: func3    
}
return d[random.choice(d.keys())]()
```

and they are actually the same.

Now I would like to do the same but without ever assigning the dictionary to a variable - is this possible? I know that the `_` operator kind of does something like that, so I was wondering whether this can be done, too.

```
return {
    1: func1,
    2: func2,
    3: func3
}[random.choice(???.keys())]()
```

I'm just asking out of curiosity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just make it a bit, uhm, *less indirect*:

```
return random.choice([func1, func2, func3])()
```

The "dictionary switch" idiom is for when you have a key which you want to map to another value. In your case this is superfluous.

Comment: Well, that's not quite what I expected, but yes. That's much better.